# How to use split-apply-combine pattern of pandas groupby() to normalize multiple columns simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, normalization, split-apply-combine

I am trying to normalize experimental data in a pandas data table that contains multiple columns with numerical observables (features), columns with date and experiment conditions as well as additional non-numerical conditions such as filenames.

I would like to

- use the split-apply-combine paradigm
- normalize within groups, using aggregate statistics of subgroups
- use different normalizations (e.g. divide-by-control-mean, Z-score)
- apply this to all numerical columns (observables)
- finally, generate an augmented data table which has the same structure as the original, but with additional columns, e.g. for column Observable1 a column normalized_Observable1 should be added

A simplified data table that has this structure can be generated with this code snippet::

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'condition': ['ctrl', 'abc', 'ctrl', 'abc', 'def', 'ctlr', 'ctlr', 'asdasd', 'afff', 'afff', 'gr1','gr2', 'gr2', 'ctrl', 'ctrl', 'kjkj','asht','ctrl'],
   'date':  ['20170131', '20170131', '20170131', '20170131','20170131', '20170606', '20170606', '20170606', '20170606', '20170606', '20170404', '20170404', '20170404', '20170404', '20170404', '20161212', '20161212', '20161212'],
   'observation1':  [1.2, 2.2, 1.3, 1.1, 2.3 , 2.3, 4.2, 3.3, 5.1, 3.3, 3.4, 5.5, 9.9, 3.2, 1.1, 3.3, 1.2, 5.4],
   'observation2':  [3.1, 2.2, 2.1, 1.2,  2.4, 1.2, 1.5, 1.33, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.3, 0.9, 0.78, 1.2, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
   'observation3':  [2.0, 1.2, 1.2, 2.01, 2.55, 2.05, 1.66, 3.2, 3.21, 3.04, 8.01, 9.1, 7.06, 8.1, 7.9, 5.12, 5.23, 5.15],
   'rawsource': ["1.tif", "2.tif", "3.tif",  "4.tif", "5.tif","6.tif", "7.tif", "8.tif", "9.tif", "10.tif", "11.tif", "12.tif", "13.tif", "14.tif", "15.tif", "16.tif", "17.tif", "18.tif"]
})
print(df)
```

and would look like this

```
   condition      date  observation1  observation2  observation3 rawsource
0       ctrl  20170131           1.2          3.10          2.00     1.tif
1        abc  20170131           2.2          2.20          1.20     2.tif
2       ctrl  20170131           1.3          2.10          1.20     3.tif
3        abc  20170131           1.1          1.20          2.01     4.tif
4        def  20170131           2.3          2.40          2.55     5.tif
5       ctlr  20170606           2.3          1.20          2.05     6.tif
6       ctlr  20170606           4.2          1.50          1.66     7.tif
7     asdasd  20170606           3.3          1.33          3.20     8.tif
8       afff  20170606           5.1          1.50          3.21     9.tif
9       afff  20170606           3.3          1.60          3.04    10.tif
10       gr1  20170404           3.4          1.40          8.01    11.tif
11       gr2  20170404           5.5          1.30          9.10    12.tif
12       gr2  20170404           9.9          0.90          7.06    13.tif
13      ctrl  20170404           3.2          0.78          8.10    14.tif
14      ctrl  20170404           1.1          1.20          7.90    15.tif
15      kjkj  20161212           3.3          4.00          5.12    16.tif
16      asht  20161212           1.2          5.00          5.23    17.tif
17      ctrl  20161212           5.4          6.00          5.15    18.tif
```

Now, for each experiment date I have different experimental conditions, but I always have condition named `ctrl`. One of normalizations I'd like to perform is to calculate the (for each numerical column) the mean of the control experiment for that date and then divide all observables from that date by their corresponding mean.

I can quickly calculate some of the per-date, per-condition summary statiscs  using:

```
grsummary = df.groupby(["date","condition"]).agg((min, max, np.nanmean, np.nanstd))
```

Then I would like to apply these summary statistics in a normalization for each experiment date:

```
grdate = df.groupby("date")
```

and apply the normalization in a fashion like this:

```
def normalize_by_ctrlmean(grp_frame, summarystats):
    #  the following is only pseudo-code as I don't know how to do this
    grp_frame/ summarystats(nanmean)

grdate.apply(normalize_by_cntrlmean, summarystats= grsummary)
```

The last step is only pseudo-code. This is what I'm struggling with. I could do the normalization using nested for-loops over dates, conditions, and column names of numerical columns but I'm new to the split-apply-combine paradigm and I think there must be a simple solution ?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how you can do this using `df.apply`:

### Split

Since you want to perform operations 'per date', you only need to split by date:

```
grdate = df.groupby("date")
```

### Apply & Combine

Next, define a transformation function that can be applied to each group, taking the group itself as an argument.

In your case, the function should compute the mean of the group's `ctrl` values and then divide all of the group's observations by this mean:

```
def norm_apply(group):

    # Select the 'ctrl' condition
    ctrl_selected = group[group['condition']=='ctrl']

    # Extract its numerical values
    ctrl_numeric = ctrl_selected.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])

    # Compute the means (column-wise)
    ctrl_means = np.nanmean(ctrl_numeric,axis=0) 

    # Extract numerical values for all conditions
    group_numeric = group.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])

    # Divide by the ctrl means
    divided = group_numeric / ctrl_means

    # Return result
    return divided
```

(You can do this as a silly one-liner, if you wish...)

```
norm_apply = lambda x : x.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]) / np.nanmean(x[x['condition']=='ctrl'].select_dtypes(include=[np.number]),axis=0)
```

Now you can simply `apply` this function to your grouped dataframe:

```
normed = grdate.apply(norm_apply)
```

This should give you the values you need, combined into the same shape/order as your original df:

```
normed.head()

>>   observation1  observation2  observation3
0          0.96      1.192308       1.25000
1          1.76      0.846154       0.75000
2          1.04      0.807692       0.75000
3          0.88      0.461538       1.25625
4          1.84      0.923077       1.59375
```

### Merge into the Original DataFrame

One way of adding these results back to the original df would be like this:

```
# Add prefix to column names
normed = normed.add_prefix('normed_')

# Concatenate with initial data frame
final = pd.concat([df,normed],axis=1)
display(final.head())
```

And finally, you can group by date and condition and look at the means:

```
final.groupby(['date','condition']).mean()
```

*If everything worked correctly, the means for the `ctlr` condition should all be `1.0`.*

---

(*Side Note:* Although Ian Thompson's answer also works, I believe this approach sticks more closely to the split-apply-combine ideology.)

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I'm kind of confused by what you are wanting with the function. I don't have enough reputation to comment so I will give my best guess to try and answer your question.

Seeing that your function is called `normalize_by_ctrlmean`, I assume that you want to always divide by the `mean` of the `ctrl` group for each year, within each observation. To do this we'll have to tidy up your data a bit using the `melt` function.

```
df1 = df.melt(id_vars = ['condition',
                         'date',
                         'rawsource'],
              value_vars = ['observation1',
                            'observation2',
                            'observation3'],
              var_name = 'observations')

df1.head()
```

[image: melt]

Next we will calculate the `mean` for the `ctrl` group

```
ctrl_mean = df1[df1.condition == 'ctrl'].groupby(['date',
                                                  'observations']).agg('mean').reset_index().rename(columns = {'value' : 'ctrl_mean'})

ctrl_mean
```

[image: ctrl_mean]

Merge this dataframe with the melted dataframe.

```
df2 = df1.merge(ctrl_mean,
                how = 'inner',
                on = ['date',
                      'observations'])

df2.head()
```

[image: merge]

And lastly, divide the `value` column by the `ctrl_mean` column and insert into the dataframe.

```
df2.insert(df2.shape[1],
           'normalize_by_ctrlmean',
           df2.loc[:, 'value'] / df2.loc[:, 'ctrl_mean'])

df2.head()
```

[image: normalize]

Hope this gets you closer to what you were needing.

**EDIT**

Per your comment I'll show how to get back to a similar dataframe you had with `observation` columns first with the `pivot_table` function, and then with the `groupby` function.

*pivot_table*

```
df2.pivot_table(index = ['date', # columns to use as the index
                   'condition',
                   'rawsource'],
          columns = 'observations', # this will make columns out of the values in this column
          values = ['value', # these will be the values in each column
                    'ctrl_mean', # swaplevel swaps the column levels (axis = 1), sort_index sorts and "smooshes" them together
                    'normalize_by_ctrlmean']).swaplevel(axis = 1).sort_index(axis = 1).reset_index() # reset_index so you can refer to specific columns
```

[image: pivot_table]

*groupby*

```
df2.groupby(['date', # groupby these columns to make the index
             'condition',
             'rawsource',
             'observations']).agg({'value' : 'max', # take the max of these as the aggregate (there was only one value for each so the max just returns that value)
                                   'ctrl_mean' : 'max', # unstack('observations') makes columns out of the 'observations'
                                   'normalize_by_ctrlmean' : 'max'}).unstack('observations').swaplevel(axis = 1).sort_index(axis = 1).reset_index() # these do the same thing as on the pivot_table example
```

[image: groupby]

In addition, you can remove the `swaplevel` and `sort_index` functions to keep the aggregate columns on the top level instead of the `observations`

[image: swap_sort]

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks that looks very good already. At least at gets me thinking in a different way. I had to read up on the pd.melt function with which I was not familiar and the difference between wide and long format. Your suggestion gets me most of the way there I think, as I can calculate the desired normalisations this way. For the downstream plotting  I will need to go back to wide format and create new columns observable1_normalized etc. Just reading up on pd.pivot on how to do this.   Will update my post once I find  a solution.